# How can I fix this: generic type in list?

Tags: c#

I am getting compile error :

> "The type or namespace name 'T' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
>   Error   3   The type or namespace name 'S' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Below is my code:

```
public static List<T> AutoCopyList(List<S> lst)
{
    List<T> ModelF = new List<T>();
    foreach (var item in lst)
    {
        var e = new T();
        e = Commn.AutoCopy<T, S>(item);
        ModelF.Add(e);
    }
    return ModelF;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should mark your method as a generic method and state explicitly that T should have a public parameterless constructor:

```
 public static List<T> AutoCopyList<S,T>(List<S> lst) where T : new()
```

For further info regarding the new constraint, `where T : new()`, please have a look [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/new-constraint).

Comment: I suggest you keep the second type in the function: `public static List<T1> AutoCopyList<T1,T2>(List<T2> lst) where T1 : new()`

Comment: @fharreau oops just saw it. Thanks ! I corrected it.

Comment: This won't compile : you are not declaring the type S in the function. And you can improve the declaration by returning a List of T (instead of a non-generic list).

Comment: @fharreau out of vs is a bit difficult :( Thanks once more !

Comment: It would be usual for the return type `T` to be the last generic type parameter.

Comment: @Enigmativity changed.